# How to allow MPI worker nodes read their own environment variables?

Tags: environment-variables, mpi

I'm using OpenMPI and mpirun, and my MPI processes are divided among multiple Docker containers. Each Docker container is running its own process that has an environment variable, say, `FOO`, where `$FOO` (i.e. its value) differs depending on the container. The process running in the master node is the one that calls the `mpirun`. Is there a way for me to get each worker node to have `FOO` set in its MPI process in the mpirun command?

My question is different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30477842/how-to-set-environment-variables-on-compute-nodes-in-an-mpi-job) in that the values of the environment variables may differ from container to container. Using `-x` in the mpirun command exports the master node's value for the environment variable, so that doesn't work for what I'm trying to do.

edit: revised to clarify based on the comment

Comment: an environment variable belongs to a process and not a container. you first need to figure out how (so to speak) "the variable is set in the container environment" and find how to have it set in a MPI task (how was it started?) running on that container.

Comment: the second part of that "how to have it set in a MPI task (how was it started?) running on that container" is what I'm looking for with this question. (I've edited the question to clarify the first part.)

Comment: Did you already figure out how "the variable is set in the container environment"? meanwhile you can try to `unset FOO` before invoking `mpirun`, that might be enough for you (`mpirun` will no more "export" the `FOO` environment variable to the MPI tasks, and hence might leave a chance for them to get the value that was already set I do not know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting in case this ends up being helpful for anyone else -

I ended up solving this by writing the environment variables to `/etc/environment` before starting the MPI process. My Docker images use Ubuntu as a base, and `/etc/environment` is honored even in a non-interactive, non-login shell (which is what MPI uses).