# Best way to get mpirun to have command inherit current environment?

Tags: mpi

When you do `mpirun env` it shows that the command doesn't inherit the current environment and I was wondering if there is a clean way (e.g. a CLI arg to MPI) to make this work?

Comment: Does the `-x` mentioned here fit your needs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30477842/how-to-set-environment-variables-on-compute-nodes-in-an-mpi-job

Comment: I'm trying to pass the entire environment, but I do appreciate the hint. This is helpful. Do you know how to pass the entire environment?

Comment: I'd suggest to set the environment in a script.sh; then `mpirun -np 12 script.sh`. Make your script template with `env > script.sh`, then finish it with `myprogram.exe $*`. But do you really want all variables? You probably don't: some are wrong or meaningless (think of `HOSTNAME` for instance, or slurm variables if you use such a thing). So a few `-x` is your best option, AFAIK.

Comment: Ok, well I already tried the env > script.sh; . script.sh idea apparently it doesn't work because env doesn't produce valid bash code.

I ended up using jsrun on my LSF system because that sets the MPI Rank environment variable (all that I needed out of mpirun) & it inherits the parent environment.